# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've built a simple login page that on clicking the button opens the menu to choose a google account and then navigates to the homepage of the app.

The button gets clicked but the login menu doesn't pop up. It throws an error saying :

```
E/flutter ( 4974): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. E/flutter ( 4974): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

I tried adding a new context to the tree but then a different error came up:

```
E/flutter (22865): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null. E/flutter (22865): Receiver: null E/flutter (22865): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType()
```

What should I do?

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sorted/screens/sortedMain.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class LoginMain extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginMain({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginMainState createState() => _LoginMainState();
}

class _LoginMainState extends State<LoginMain> {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser _user;

  bool isUserSignedIn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    checkIfUserIsSignedIn();
  }

  void checkIfUserIsSignedIn() async {
    var userSignedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();

    setState(() {
      isUserSignedIn = userSignedIn;
    });
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
    FirebaseUser user;
    bool userSignedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();

    setState(() {
      isUserSignedIn = userSignedIn;
    });

    if (isUserSignedIn) {
      user = await _auth.currentUser();
    } else {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      userSignedIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
      setState(() {
        isUserSignedIn = userSignedIn;
      });
    }
    _user = user;
    return user;
  }

  void onGoogleSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _handleSignIn().then((value) => null);
    BuildContext context;
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SortedMain(_googleSignIn, user)),
    );

    setState(() {
      isUserSignedIn == null ? true : false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Sorted.'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff0A3D62),
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      colors: <Color>[
                    const Color(0xFF5761B2),
                    const Color(0xFF1FC588),
                  ])),
            ),
          ),
          drawer: null,
          body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              width: 360,
              height: 600,
              color: const Color(0xFF273748),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 300,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.grey[400]]),
                      ),
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        height: 50.0,
                        minWidth: 150.0,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        splashColor: Colors.teal,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                        onPressed: () {
                          BuildContext context;
                          onGoogleSignIn(context);
                        },
                      )),
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try remove the  MaterialApp from your build method

Comment: Didn't work. Wouldn't load the screen at all saying safe area requires a media query widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the code below for setting up your firebase class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class AuthProvider {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }


  Future<bool> loginWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      GoogleSignInAccount account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (account == null) return false;
      AuthResult res =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        idToken: (await account.authentication).idToken,
        accessToken: (await account.authentication).accessToken,
      ));
      if (res.user == null) return false;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error logging with google");
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  Future<void> logOut() async {
    try {
      await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print("error logging out");
    }
  }
}
class User {

final String uid;

  User({ this.uid });

}
```

and try restricting your Navigator with an `if` statement so it can't navigate without the completion of the login process.

```
CustomButtom(
       onpressed :  () async {
              bool res = await AuthProvider().loginWithGoogle();
              if (res) {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SortedMain()));
              } else
                print("Login failed");
            },
        ),
```

Comment: Hi Apurv! I'm unable to import import 'package:login_info_intro_st/models/user.dart'; and consequently can't use the User object. Is it a model I need to structure myself?

Comment: Hi Nimai, I have changes the code. Kindly take a look now!

Comment: Hi Apurv, it's still throwing me the:

'E/flutter (13874): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
E/flutter (13874): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.'

-when I press the login button

Comment: This error is unrelated to the destination. It happens because you used a context that doesn't contain a Navigator instance as parent.

Comment: Hence instead of creating a new Context, you can pass the same context over a function.

Comment: I'm confused. Since I'm not creating a new context, isn't it the original context I'm using and hence it should work? And if not, how do I correct it?

Comment: delete  the BuildContext context line in the function onGoogleSignIn(). That second build context is creating the problem. Just declare the function like below -                                              
             void onGoogleSignIn(BuildContext context) async {},